# how to get value from one adapter to another adapter using recyclerview in android?

Tags: android-recyclerview

How to get value from one adapter to another adapter when clicking on the favorite button then it shows how many we clicked on favorite image button and also shows all data in another activity. Below is my Adapter Class & ViewHolder class (i.e **AdapterFav.java** & **ContactViewHolder.java**)

**AdapterFav.java**

```
    public class AdapterFav extends 
        RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterFav.ContactViewHolder>{

        private ArrayList<Contactfav> contactfavList;
        private static Context mContext;

        public AdapterFav(ArrayList<Contactfav> contactfavList, Context applicationContext) {
            this.contactfavList = contactfavList;
            this.mContext = applicationContext;
        }

        @Override
        public ContactViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.contact_row, null);
            ContactViewHolder contactViewHolder = new ContactViewHolder(view);
            return contactViewHolder;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ContactViewHolder holder, int position) {
            Contactfav contactfav = (Contactfav) contactfavList.get(position);
            holder.tvContactName.setText(contactfav.getContactName());
            holder.tvPhoneNumber.setText(contactfav.getContactNumber());
            //Log.e("Id is", contactfav.getContactNumber());
            holder.ivContactImage.setImageBitmap(contactfav.getContactImage());
            holder.id=contactfav.getCid();
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return contactfavList.size();    
        }
    }
```

**ContactViewHolder.java**

```
 public static class ContactViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView ivContactImage;
        ImageButton ibFavBtn;
        TextView tvContactName;
        TextView tvPhoneNumber;
        Contactfav contactfav=new Contactfav();
        String id;
        public ContactViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ivContactImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivContactImage);
            tvContactName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvContactName);
            tvPhoneNumber = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPhoneNumber);
            ibFavBtn = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.fav);

            ibFavBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                Boolean b = true;

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (b == true) {
                        ibFavBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.star2);
                        Log.e("From get", id);
                        b = false;

                    } else {
                        ibFavBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);
                        b = true;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
  }
```

Comment: are you getting data from server?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @farhana thank you madam fro reading my question ... i am sorry to say  i did not get proper way of the program .. so i confused to in Adapter.

Comment: You can also use interface. May be it will solve you issue